# Is Polymorphism and Method Overloading almost the same thing in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

In C++, there are 2 types of Polymorphism:

1. Object Polymorphism
2. Function Polymorphism

Function polymorphism is exactly the same thing as method or **function overloading** i.e. We use the same method names with different parameters and return types. Now the question is why do we have this fancy name **Polymorphism** in OOP?

What distinctly distinguishes polymorphism from method overloading? Can someone explain with a scenario. Thanks

Comment: There's a third kind: parametric polymorphism via templates. "Object polymorphism" probably refers to subtype polymorphism (overriding of virtual member functions).

Comment: Note that what I think you mean by object polymorphism is more formally called subtype polymorphism, or simply polymorphism in OO contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphism means "multiple forms".

In computer science there are mainly three different kinds of polymorphism:

- Adhoc polymorphism

  - Function overloading
  - C++ template specialization
- Subtype polymorphism

  - subclassing and virtual methods
- Parametric polymorphism

  - C++ templates
  - C# and Java Generics
  - Polymorphic functions in ML

Polymorphism is a concept. AdHoc polymorphism means same name different implementation.

```
// Function overloading
void f(A a);  
void f(B b);
// template specialization
template <typename T> class A;  
template <> class A<int> {}  
template <> class A<float> {}
```

Comment: Here I always thought it was the metamorphosis stage of nylon worms.

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism: Poly => Multiple, Morph => Form.

To make it simple, there are many polymorphism mechanism in C++ and Function Overloading is one type of polymorphism.

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/cpp-polymorphism/

Answer (score 2):

The essence of polymorphism is ability to provide **different behavior by single syntax form** (typically function call in C++). By this definition virtual function call (that actually represents OOP polymorphism) and overloaded function call are both polymorphic.

The difference between them is *how* and *when* specific behavior is selected in each case.

For virtual function call it's made in *run-time* according to dynamic type of object which function member is called. (Of course, if called via base class pointer or reference. If called directly it will be selected in compile-time).

For overloaded function call it's made in *compile-time* according to signature of function call (types and number of arguments + cv-qualifiers).

So in brief the difference - overloading is **static** polymorphism, resolved in compile-time, virtual function is **dynamic** polymorphism, resolved in run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is not the same as method overloading.  From wikipedia:

> polymorphism is not the same as method overloading or method
>   overriding,[1] (that is known instead as ad-hoc polymorphism [2]).
>   Polymorphism is only concerned with the application of specific
>   implementations to an interface or a more generic base class. Method
>   overloading refers to methods that have the same name but different
>   signatures inside the same class. Method overriding is where a
>   subclass replaces the implementation of one or more of its parent's
>   methods. Neither method overloading nor method overriding are by
>   themselves implementations of polymorphism

In polymorphism, the methods are overridden not overloaded (meaning the child objects have their own implementation of the inherited function but it has the same signature).  So what you are calling function polymorphism is really just method overloading or ad-hoc polymorphism.

Comment: Just to let you know, that quote is dead **wrong**. Function overloading **is** a type of polymorphism.

Comment: @JesseGood It's correct if we take polymorphism as *subtype* polymorphism, which is done very often in OO contexts. I don't like the convention either, but it's so common we have to consider that unspoken assumption when reviewing text on the topic.

Comment: @delnan: I agree. If you look at the actual [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming), the actual quote was cut off and had `Subtype` in parentheses at the beginning. Although, that article and wording in the quote is very poor in general and could use a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The two things are defined as:

**Static Polymorphism**: Association of overloaded function is called Static polymorphism.

**Function Overloading**: When more than one function\Context exist with different behaviour\signature, then it is called Function Overloading.

**Note**: If one function exist with different signature and we have not binded those functions with an object we can't say that static Polymorphism is there.

Comment: Could you provide a source for you definitions?